# Orange Pi Ubuntu Jammy unable to login new user

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

i added new user in my orange pi using the gnome user manager. Apparently after i try to login, it just show white screen with message: "Oh no! Something has gone wrong. A problem has occured and the system can't recover. Please log out and try again."

But this doesn't happened on:

1. `orangepi` user using gnome desktop
2. the same user using different desktop, like `KDE plasma`

Apparently the same issue also happened if i use debian. So something maybe wrong with gnome desktop?